# Идентификация alarmManager

Tags: java, android, android-alarm-manager

Как я могу идентифицировать alarmManager, Нужно узнать если alarmManager уже создан тогда не создавать больше

```
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, inetIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 2 * AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HOUR, pendingIntent);
```

В таком варианте, он как бы отменяет текущее и создает новое которое срабатывает сразу же

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот [тут](https://github.com/mohaxspb/ScpFoundationRu/blob/master/scp2/src/main/java/ru/dante/scpfoundation/manager/MyNotificationManager.java) отлаженная лично и используемая в продакшене версия установки, отмены и проверки наличия `AlarmManager`-a. Проверять наличие зарегистрированного `AlarmManager` можно так:

```
//кажется, важно использовать при создании и проверки один и тот же контекст
//ReceiverTimer.class - это тот ресивер, который реагирует на созданный ранее и нуждающийся в проверке `AlarmManager`
Intent intent2check = new Intent(mContext.getApplicationContext(), ReceiverTimer.class);
//устанавливаем и action, если надо
intent2check.setAction(mContext.getString(R.string.receiver_action_timer));
//проверяем наличие не создавая с помощью флага PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE
//если AlarmManager установлен, то будет !null
boolean alarmUp = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext.getApplicationContext(), ID, intent2check,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);
```

Comment: если нету он вернет null, а если есть он обновит текущий pending intent и счет времени начнется новый?

Comment: @JNat, если уже существует, что ничего не изменится. Флаг  `PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE` не даст чему либо создасться. Т.е. после этой проверки вы можете ничего не делать и старый аларм останется на месте

Comment: получается флаг не создает в любом случае, а нужен фактически только для проверки. А то я понять не мог зачем такой флаг нужен)